# MVC returns invalid json when an exeption is thrown

Tags: c#, json, angular, model-view-controller

I have simple function

```
public ActionResult GetUserList(int? departmentid)
        {
                return Content(list.GetJson(departmentid), "application/Json");    
        }
```

I call this with Angular

```
$http.post('/StockAssignment/GetUserList', { departmentid: departmentId}).then(
    function (data) {  /* all ok, do stuff */ }, 
    function(data) { /* show the error, Witch should be in data.data.msg }
);
```

This works just fine, until something in the list.GetJson function throws an error. I would like to display that error using angular, but the result is not valid JSON. Here is an example of the returned data:

```
{ "msg" : "Unable to process the type 'Anonymous type', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, NewArrayExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.GroupJoinTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectManyTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Norconsult.Extensions.JsonHelpers.GetJson(Object o) in C:\Users\hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Norconsult\Norconsult\Extensions\JsonHelpers.cs:line 57"}
```

Angular is not able to read this, and throws an error:

```
Error: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$http/baddata?p0=%7B%20%22msg%22%20%3A%20%22Unable%20to%20process%20the%20type%20'Anonymous%20type'%2C%20because%20it%20has%20no%20known%20mapping%20to%20the%20value%20layer.%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20NewArrayExpression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20ConstantExpression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.GroupJoinTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20MethodCallExpression%20call)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20MethodCallExpression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20MethodCallExpression%20call%2C%20DbExpression%26%20source%2C%20DbExpressionBinding%26%20sourceBinding%2C%20DbExpression%26%20lambda)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectManyTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20MethodCallExpression%20call)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter%20parent%2C%20MethodCallExpression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression%20linq)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable%601%20forMergeOption)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery%601.%3C%3Ec__DisplayClass7.%3CGetResults%3Eb__6()%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction%5BT%5D(Func%601%20func%2C%20IDbExecutionStrategy%20executionStrategy%2C%20Boolean%20startLocalTransaction%2C%20Boolean%20releaseConnectionOnSuccess)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery%601.%3C%3Ec__DisplayClass7.%3CGetResults%3Eb__5()%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute%5BTResult%5D(Func%601%20operation)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery%601.GetResults(Nullable%601%20forMergeOption)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery%601.%3CSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%3CT%3E.GetEnumerator%3Eb__0()%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator%601.MoveNext()%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter%20writer%2C%20IEnumerable%20values%2C%20JsonArrayContract%20contract%2C%20JsonProperty%20member%2C%20JsonContainerContract%20collectionContract%2C%20JsonProperty%20containerProperty)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter%20writer%2C%20Object%20value%2C%20JsonObjectContract%20contract%2C%20JsonProperty%20member%2C%20JsonContainerContract%20collectionContract%2C%20JsonProperty%20containerProperty)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter%20writer%2C%20Object%20value%2C%20JsonObjectContract%20contract%2C%20JsonProperty%20member%2C%20JsonContainerContract%20collectionContract%2C%20JsonProperty%20containerProperty)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter%20writer%2C%20IEnumerable%20values%2C%20JsonArrayContract%20contract%2C%20JsonProperty%20member%2C%20JsonContainerContract%20collectionContract%2C%20JsonProperty%20containerProperty)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter%20jsonWriter%2C%20Object%20value%2C%20Type%20objectType)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter%20jsonWriter%2C%20Object%20value%2C%20Type%20objectType)%0D%0A%20%20%20at%20Norconsult.Extensions.JsonHelpers.GetJson(Object%20o)%20in%20C%3A%5CUsers%5Chp%5CDocuments%5CVisual%20Studio%202017%5CProjects%5CNorconsult%5CNorconsult%5CExtensions%5CJsonHelpers.cs%3Aline%2057%22%7D&p1=%7B%7D
```

What can I do to be able to read the exeption?

Answer (score -1):

it's refering to the link:

[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/baddata?p0=)

Which tells you it's bad data, futher more.

```
msg%22%20%3A%20%22Unable%20to%20process%20the%20type%20'Anonymous%20type'%2C%20because%20it%20has%20no%20known%20mapping%20to%20the%20value%20layer.%20%20%20at%20System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.TypedTranslate
```

which IS

```
msg unable to process the type anonymous type because it has no known mapping to the value layer.System.Data.entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(so on)
```

Btw it's Accii in the url.

Comment: I'm fully aware it's bad data, my question is WHY the exeption is badly formated JSON (and not properly formated so I could read the msg with data.data.msg)